# What is 'Markdown: Open Preview to the Side' shortcut in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I have a question about shortcut of 'Markdown: Open Preview to the Side'. According to the [wiki of Markdown](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown), the shortcut is `Ctrl+K V`. What is that meaning? I tried `Ctrl+K+V`, but it didn't work.

I am using Linux Mint 20.

Comment: Press Ctrl+K, let go of K (but not of Ctrl) and then press V

Comment: Thank you, it worked. This is the weirdest shortcut I have ever seen.

Comment: These are very common in Visual Studio and IIRC also IntelliJ.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, let go of <kbd>K</kbd> (but not of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) and then press <kbd>V</kbd>.